# Couldn't connect to mongodb on mongodb-atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

Trying to connect to the mongodb free database on mongodb-atlas
I've almost tried everything Checked the docs, Changed the url, Changing password and even deleted the user and created the new one but still not resolve the problem

### here is myurl.js file

```
module.exports = {
    mongoURL: "mongodb+srv://nansDB:nansDB123@nodecluster-qs6cv.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
    secret: "mystrongsecret"
}
```

### here is my index.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();

//mongodb Configuration
const db = require('./setup/myurl').mongoURL;

//attempt to connect to database
mongoose.connect(db,  { useNewUrlParser: true })
        .then(()=> console.log('MongoDb Connect successfully'))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
```

### here are the error lines I'm getting whenever I tried to run

```
{ MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [nodecluster-shard-00-02-qs6cv.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 5 to nodecluster-shard-00-02-qs6cv.mongodb.net:27017 closed]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (D:\nodejsProject\bigStack\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:431:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at connect (D:\nodejsProject\bigStack\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:557:14)
    at callback (D:\nodejsProject\bigStack\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connect.js:109:5)
    at runCommand (D:\nodejsProject\bigStack\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connect.js:129:7)
    at Connection.errorHandler (D:\nodejsProject\bigStack\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connect.js:321:5)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (D:\nodejsProject\bigStack\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:350:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at _handle.close (net.js:597:12)
    at TCP.done (_tls_wrap.js:388:7)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

Comment: Have you setup allowed ip addrss on security tab ?

Comment: Probably didn't whitelist your ip. Also check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56586161/11330560

Comment: yes i whitelisted my ip i've done that

Comment: plz help me @ArdyFebriansyah

Comment: plz help me @MatinSasan

Comment: User and pass used in url should be the one you created as a user for your cluster. Check whether you use vpn. whitelist all ips temporarily. Connect from another ISP. Also check if you can connect via MongoDB Compass. Let me know.

Comment: Thanks @MatinSasan actually the whitelisted ip was changed because of connection problem reconnecting to wifi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its solved actually my whitelisted ip was changed because of connection issue [reconnecting to wifi]. Although my suggestion is checked whether the ip you whitelisted is exists or not.